# combine string with hdfs command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have to copy many files from one hdfs location to another.  I wrote a command to identify the "source" files:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /archive/reporting/some_dir | awk '{print $6,$7,$8}' | grep 2019-01-1
```

This gets me a list of 140+ files I want to copy.  Rather than paste the output into a text editor and pre-pend each line with "hdfs dfs -cp" I would like to prepend the output of my "ls" command with the copy command.  So, in one line I want to produce output like:

```
hdfs dfs -cp /archive/reporting/some_dir/file1
hdfs dfs -cp /archive/reporting/some_dir/file1
...
...
```

Can anyone help me with the syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the results of your one-liner and do all kinds of stuff. In your case:

```
for i in `hdfs dfs -ls /archive/reporting/some_dir | awk '{print $6,$7,$8}' | grep 2019-01-1`; do
   echo "hdfs dfs -cp $i"
done
```